# how to configure spring mvc on java8

Tags: spring-mvc, java-8, weblogic

i config spring web mvc on java 6.It was run successfully on weblogic 12.1.3
when i change java-6 to java-8,the below error is raised

> No qualifying bean of type [weblogic.server.ServerService] Caused By:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [weblogic.server.ServerService] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@javax.inject.Inject(),
>   @javax.inject.Named(value=DiagnosticFoundationService)} at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1118)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>   Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
> > 

my config of project and class file:
web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Baharan-Framework</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!--start Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!--end Spring MVC -->


</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sampleSpring</groupId>
    <artifactId>sampleSpring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>sampleSpring</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

java controller:

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("test")
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping("method1")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("In the name of god...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ask question,finally i find the problem
The problem is value of base-package in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
 (`<context:component-scan base-package="com" />`).
i change value of it(`<context:component-scan base-package="tt" />`) then the problem is solved.
when value of it was `com`,Spring going to load any class into package of com in another liberary.